# Linux boot: md raid FS not ready (sometimes)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, boot, md

Using Ubuntu 11.04 (latest patched)

I have 5 RAID-1 file systems that are automatically assembled during the boot process

(Note: none of the system FS `/`, `/usr`... are raid, only user FSes).

Once in a while, during boot, an MD cannot be assembled (seemingly) and Ubuntu asks
(*edit: exact message*)

```
 The disk drive for '/home/development' is not ready yet or is not present.
 You may keep waiting; Skip the drive; Manual recovery
```

But the FS will never be ready. After a reboot, it usually becomes available.
It happens sometimes - not always the same MD - I saw quickly that a FS was being checked just before it happened today.

It seems to be a kind of *race condition* between `mdadm` and the FS checking system, and this would be a bug IMO.
*edit* It happens sometimes, even if no FS was being checked...

Any idea?

---

*mdadm.conf*:

```
 ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=00.90 UUID=121f2e3b:415a1234:abcdb5ce:5f9876d3
 ...
```

*fstab*:

```
 /dev/md0 /home/development ext4    defaults,relatime        1       2
 ...
```

**Edit Feb 2012**

I don't think it is a bug per se. Even in Ubuntu 11.10 (latest as of today) the problem persists (and none of my drives / FS are corrupted).

It is very likely to be related to the **rc.d** order of operations.
It seems the drives are still being checked, or are not ready yet for some reasons, while `mdadm` tries - too early - to make the associations between the two disks, and fails.

Any new idea is welcome.

Comment: when the error message appears and you skip mounting, which is the output of cat /proc/mdstat ?

Comment: The FS can not be checked until mdadm activates the raid array, since the FS lives on the array.  If the array is never activated even after waiting plenty of time, then you will need to check the logs and /proc/mdstat to see why the array failed to activate.

Comment: Thanks. The MD stat shows that an array (or two), out of 5, are not activated (same status when, once a month early Sunday, MD syncs the mirror). Then I reboot, and with a 90% probability, the MD are bound and active OK. Now, I wonder if it is not a problem with my Gigabyte Motherboard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found two answers.

1. **The** answer (update 2012-05-02)

There was a problem after the update from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10.
And the MD arrays are not ready yet, when they are tested by the system.
A race condition.

The solution was on **[ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11388915&postcount=18)**

2. Floppy disk problem

   Opened the box, and

   - checked all cables and connections. Same problem after reboot.
   - The (S.M.A.R.T enabled) disks showed no problem anyway.
   - Tested the memory: ok

I tried to remove some external connections, and when I did for the floppy disk... The boot was faster and clean. Did it several times, cold start after removing power cable etc... OK!

So the culprit was the floopy disk. Not sure if it is an issue with the MB (Gigabyte P55-UD3R), Ubuntu (don't think so) or the floppy drive itself - and I didn't notice any relevant log that could lead to a hardware issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a bug.  Report it to Ubuntu unless you feel like fixing it yourself.

Comment: report it either you fix it or not. To me it looks a problem with upstart's mdadm setup

Answer (score 0):

From the fstab(5) man page:

> The fourth field (fs_mntops):

...

> nofail
>           do  not  report  errors  for  this  device if it does not
>                        exist.

If you add this option, the error shouldn't appear, but the fs should be mounted when it's ready.